# Executing <script src="..."> tag with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, gwt

I have a webapp, built with GWT (meaning its 100% ajax) and I want to include a stumbleupon badge to my site (a stumbleupon badge is similar to facebook-like button). These badges are a  that, when the page loads, it attaches an iframe with a button.

The problem is that I would like to dynamically put that  tag, but it just doesnt work. What Im doing is adding dynamically a  
but it wont work. It just does not display anything.

Comment: Obviously the problem with your code is that there isn't any.

Comment: Please post code or use [jsfiddle.net](http://www.jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: My crystal ball (although a little murky) seems to say that this is a cross domain ajax issue

Comment: Im sorry, but my original question was well put, however, It was changed (maby by some admin or moderator). Anyway, my question was regarding the stubmleupon badges code, which you can check out here http://www.stumbleupon.com/badges/ the code is <script src="http://www.stumbleupon.com/hostedbadge.php?s=5"></script> As you can see, it is not obvious why it works as it is only a <script src="...">

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you're using something like `element.innerHTML = '<script src="..."></script>';`. That is not going to work since script elements are never evaluated when setting the `innerHTML` of an element.

To include a script dynamically, use something in the sense of:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "...";
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

You can make your webapp output the URL's to be loaded or use regular expressions to attempt to parse the scripts out of the response.